# Incomplete files moved on Windows NFS

Tags: java, windows, locking, move, nfs

I have a Unix system mounting an NFS "share" from a Windows server. On the Windows server I have a PowerShell script that will check every 10 s if there is a new file coming in on the NFS share and Move-Item it somewhere else and then it gets processed further.

What we are seeing is that files are corrupted in this process. My hunch is that the NFS writing takes a little longer, the script picks up an incomplete file and Move-Item it to the other folder. There is also a theory a colleague has that the further processing picks up the file before Move-Item has completed. I do not believe in that theory, because Move-Item on the same file system should be an atomic metadata only operation. (Don't be confused by the NFS reference, the Windows server has these files locally, the NFS share is mounted by the Unix system, so Move-Item does not involve NFS, and in my case, doesn't cross file system boundaries either.)

Either way, I want to know why it would be that the writing of the file to NFS which is by a Java process on Unix, is not locking the file on the Windows host file system? Would I have to explicitly on Java cause an NFS lock to be set somehow? Is there even support for fcntl lock feature from Java?

Also, if I used power-shell Copy command rather than Move-Item, there would be a certain moment of file incomplete copied. Isn't the Copy command automatically setting a lock on the destination file until it is finished?

EDIT: This is actually getting more and more puzzling. First I tried locking the file explicitly while writing to the NFS. This is Java and it creates a huge problem with NFS, I couldn't set up the nlockmgr service to actually work, there is a firewall involved between the two, I made all the right passages, and get no response to the lock requests from the Windows NFS server. This causes the Java side to completely hang, so bad you can't even kill -KILL the JVM. The only way to end this nightmare is to reboot the Unix system, crazy! There also isn't a timeout on the lock request, big problem in Java, other places like read from socket I have seen such problems too, you can't kill a thread that hangs reading from a socket. Whatever, there is no way to cancel a lock request. So I gave up on that.

Then I added a filter in the PowerShell script to only move files that have a last written to time less than 10 seconds before the current time. That should leave more than enough time for the writer to finish. But apparently it doesn't help either.

UPDATE: but yes, I now watched it, that copy process on Unix from S3 to NFS to Windows NTFS takes a long time, and it is all running on AWS so even S3 should be considered fast. Yet, it crawls between 0 kB ... 64 kB ... 90 kB with 10 seconds not enough to wait between each new chunk written. I updated this wait time to 30 seconds and that seems to work, but it is not guaranteed.

The locking would be the right solution, but I have 2 major obstacles:

1. can't get the Windows NFS "share" to work with mounted on Unix and nlockmgr service playing
2. Java JVM will totally stall unkillable if the nlockmgs has a problem.

Comment: java is missing as a tag

Comment: @Dennis, which tag you propose to sacrifice? Can`t have more then 5.

Comment: The `move`-tag perhaps? `locking` seems to be the central issue and the systems involved. And I think you really would benefit of java-guys finding your question :)